# Same outer join relative order but different absolute orders

Tags: mysql, sql

The question title might be confusing because I couldn't think of a succinct way to form the question. Let me describe with an example.

I have a query (using MySQL 5.6) that roughly looks like this:

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM
  a
  -- Left joins a with b1, then b1 with b2
  LEFT JOIN ... AS b1
    ON b1.a_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN ... AS b2
    ON b2.b1_id = b1.id
  -- Left joins a with c1, then c1 with c2
  LEFT JOIN ... AS c1
    ON c1.a_id = a.id
  LEFT JOIN ... AS c2
    ON c2.c1_id = c1.id
  -- Inner joins a with some other tables i1, i2, i3
  ...
WHERE
  ...
```

Let's write the order of tables in the query above as `a b1 b2 c1 c2 i1 i2 i3`. However, because the dependency tree of these tables actually looks like

```
a --> b1 -> b2
  |
   -> c1 -> c2
  |
   -> i1
  |
   -> i2
  |
   -> i3
```

I believe rearranging the tables as `a c1 c2 b1 b2 i1 i2 i3` doesn't make a difference (but please correct me if I'm wrong).

However, when I was fiddling with the query, I noticed that the query still works with `a b1 c1 b2 c2 i1 i2 i3`, `a b1 c1 c2 b2 i1 i2 i3`, and even `a i1 b1 i2 c1 i3 b2 i4 c2`. It seems as if as long as the relative order of `a b1 b2` and `a c1 c2` are maintained, the absolute order doesn't affect the query results.

I'm wondering if this is just by coincidence, or is actually guaranteed by SQL.

Comment: Look at the `EXPLAIN {query}` differences. I think you'll see provide the query is functionally the same, the query plan will be the same.

Comment: "I believe rearranging the tables as..." -- What do you mean by rearranging? SQL is a declarative language, not an imperative one. The optimizer is free to rephrase, reorder, re-compose, refactor the query internally, so long it returns the result you specified.

Comment: @TheImpaler By rearranging I mean just literally write the tables in the `FROM` clause in different orders. I asked this because I know the order of outer joins matters, but I don't know if it's the *absolute* order that matters or only the *relative* order.

Comment: For INNER JOIN, order doesn't matter at all, it's commutative and associative. For LEFT and RIGHT JOIN, relative order matters only between the tables in the `ON` clause. But the order of unrelated joins doesn't matter.

Comment: @Barmar This is exactly what I'm asking. Maybe make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `INNER JOIN`, order doesn't matter at all, it's commutative and associative.

For `OUTER JOIN`, relative order matters only between the tables in the ON clause; if it's a `LEFT JOIN` the first table is the master for the joining condition, for `RIGHT JOIN` the second table is the master.

However, the relative order of independent joins is irrelevant. So if `table1` is the master and `table2` and `table3` are both dependent on it, there's no difference between

```
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.t1_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.t1_id
```

and

```
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3 ON table1.id = table3.t1_id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.t1_id
```

Comment: The only time I've seen the relative order being relevant is for simpler engines, such as Derby or HyperSQL. I'm not sure, but on one of them the optimizer follows the exact order of the tables as typed in the query.